# Zero returned getting url parameter in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to get parameter passed with url ..and it returns 0.

Here is the ManagedBean...A simple bean with two variables.

```
    import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;


    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped

    public class UserBean {

        @ManagedProperty("#{param.id}")

        private int id;
        private String name;
        public int getId() {
            System.out.println(id);
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            System.out.println(id);
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public UserBean() {
            super();
        }

        public String createUrl()
        {
            return "yoga.xhtml?id=267";
        }


    }
```

Here is the xhtml page from where the parameter is passed...I'm using commandButton to redirect to a page with a query param

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
</head>
<h:body>

<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{userBean.id}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:form>
<h:commandButton action = "yoga.xhtml?id=345" value = "click here to pass the paramter">

</h:commandButton>
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

And this is where I'm redirecting the page to display the id passed

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">


<h:body>

Passed Parameter is
<h1>#{userBean.id}</h1>


</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's been a while since I used JSF but isn't there a `<h:param>` tag that can be nested inside `<h:commandButton>`? Besides that it could be the `<f:viewParam>` which reads the initial value of `id` and overrides what you pass in the action. Since `id` is of type `int` the initial value will be 0.

Comment: @Thomas: Close ... it's `<f:param>`. OP should certainly be using it.

Comment: @EJP yeah my memory told me it probably was `<f:param>` but some other memory told me there was a change in the namespaces - so I got fooled here. :)

Comment: changed it to f:param...still its returning 0   @Thomas

Comment: Please avoid plain HTML `<head>`. `<f:param name="id" value="..."/>` inside `<h:commandButton>` should function.

Comment: ok..got it..!! works without <h:commandButton> as well.